# Undefined control sequence. \xpretobibmacro{textcite} after updating MikTeX database

Tags: biblatex, biber

Hellow.

After that I updated the MikTeX database, whenever I compile any latex code using biblatex with ABNT style, this follow error happens:

> `Undefined control sequence. \xpretobibmacro{textcite} after updating MikTeX database.`

I can compile using such TeXStudio as commmand line that this error always repeats. I am going to put a MWE for analyzes and tests.

I thank for help in advance.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=abnt,ittitles]{biblatex}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{TELFORD1990,
        author    = {William Murray Telford and Lloyd Philip Geldart and Robert Edward Sheriff},
        title     = {Applied geophysics},
        edition   = {2},
        address   = {Cambridge},
        publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
        year      = {1990}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{Estilo \texttt{abnt}}
        \vspace{1em}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            COMANDO & SAÍDA ATUAL & SUGERIDA \\ \midrule
            \verb+\cite{TELFORD1990}+       & \cite{TELFORD1990}        & \CheckmarkBold    \\ \midrule
            \verb+\cite*{TELFORD1990}+      & \cite*{TELFORD1990}       & ---               \\ \midrule
            \verb+\citetitle{TELFORD1990}+  & \citetitle{TELFORD1990}   & \CheckmarkBold    \\ \midrule
            \verb+\citetitle*{TELFORD1990}+ & \citetitle*{TELFORD1990}  & Applied geophysics\\ \midrule
            \verb+\citeyear{TELFORD1990}+   & \citeyear{TELFORD1990}    & \CheckmarkBold    \\ \midrule
            \verb+\citeyear*{TELFORD1990}+  & \citeyear*{TELFORD1990}   & \CheckmarkBold    \\ \midrule
            \verb+\citeauthor{TELFORD1990}+ & \citeauthor{TELFORD1990}  & \CheckmarkBold    \\ \midrule
            \verb+\citeauthor*{TELFORD1990}+& \citeauthor*{TELFORD1990} & \CheckmarkBold    \\ \midrule
            \verb+\textcite{TELFORD1990}+   & \textcite{TELFORD1990}    & \CheckmarkBold    \\ \midrule
            \verb+\textcite*{TELFORD1990}+  & \textcite*{TELFORD1990}   & Telford, Geldart e Sheriff \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No error for me with an up-to-date TeX Live. Can you please report the exact error message you find in the log file?

Comment: Did you update in user *and* admin mode?

Comment: The example as posted works for me on a fully updated MikTeX system. Definitely check that you updated in User and Admin mode as Ulrike says: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864. If that does not help we need to see the `.log` file. Run the minimised version of your example document from https://gist.github.com/moewew/b1acc005108dc5befbecfcc14904f3f2 and upload the complete `.log` file to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/, https://gitlab.com/explore/snippets

Comment: Also posted at https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt/issues/83

Comment: Indeed, I had not updated the MikTeX as admin mode. I forgot to do it. But I have updated the FNDB and the font map files in MikTeX console as admin mode, and whenever I have been running that MWE in command line, that error 

`> Undefined control sequence. \xpretobibmacro{textcite} after updating MikTeX database.`

has been repeting as the same way.

Comment: @moewe, I am going to run [gist.github.com/moewew/b1acc005108dc5befbecfcc14904f3f2](http://gist.github.com/moewew/b1acc005108dc5befbecfcc14904f3f2) and passing the .log by [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com), according to you asked to me

Comment: @moewe, I have runned your code, whose is avaliable in [gist.github.com/moewew/b1acc005108dc5befbecfcc14904f3f2](http://gist.github.com/moewew/b1acc005108dc5befbecfcc14904f3f2), and that error has been repeating yet. In this same link, I putted an answer with the .log file that was resulting of running.

Comment: Your version of `xpatch` is outdated: You have `xpatch 2012/10/02 v0.3`, but the current version in MikTeX is `xpatch 2020/03/25 v0.3a`. Run a package update in the MikTeX Console in Admin mode.

Comment: @moewe, I tested your suggestion that updating the `xpatch` package. Indeed there was something wrong. When I went to check the version of this package, to my surprise, I had noted that it was not installed! It is so strange! Same thing happend with the `beamer` class and your package set. Because of that, I had the problem `Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}` with `beamer`. I don't know why it's happening after updating the MikTeX packages. By the way, I would like to ask to you formalizing your suggestion as an answer in order to I can sinalize as the problem solution. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of `xpatch` is outdated: You have `xpatch 2012/10/02 v0.3`, but the current version in MikTeX is `xpatch 2020/03/25 v0.3a`.

On your system  `xpatch` is installed in the MikTeX Admin tree. So it should be enough to run a package update in the MikTeX Console in Admin mode. If that does not help remove the package (if possible) and re-install it via the MikTeX Console (again in Admin mode).